# Enteprise software for asset management to track software both as intellectual property and digital assets?

Tags: software-development, business-intelligence, resource-management

Typically, software like SAP offers tools for asset management from the perspective of business process. If a company builds a building, that asset could be managed.

But what if a company invests considerable resources to build own software services? Technically, the assets are for example code repositories and software packages which have their dependencies etc.

From what I have seen so far, these digital assets are often not visible to the enterprise resource management because IT and software are considered to be a "service" which is partly true as business function, but nobody would say it's a service to have and maintain a building. It's an asset. So an enterprise information system especially if built by the company, itself or delegated, is somehow an asset too.

So my question is - what are existing solutions, if any, which consider digital software assets and elements of IT enterprise architectures to be part of enterprise resources?

In the infrastructure business, hyperscalers have done a good job by building their own software following service-by-value model instead of service-by-time to introduce valuable and realistic shared resource management.

Comment: This seems like a very interesting premise indeed. However, I wonder if the requirement is fully defined here. What I mean by that is the code repositories and software packages are at a macro level digital assets pretty much the same way as say organisation logo and associated branding media. If this definition works for you then perhaps it falls under the category of "Digital Asset Management" and an opensource tool such as https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore will be a good fit but then I am not entirely sure if such a management of assets will work for the usecase you have in mind.

Comment: @techbolt yes and now, I think it has to be also an integration with GitLab as primary storage and intelligence for repos. There are also products to store binary assets / containers. But these tools are for technical management and miss the business operations integration (while those people deal with time booking on projects which is kind of virtual business but these are terms operatable in the service-by-time focused model).

Comment: hmm... could you perhaps explain what you mean by "miss the business operations integration" with an example or a usecase. Like what do you expect a user of this software to be able to accomplish?

Comment: @techbolt associate finance and HR controlling with project/service status for example based on data about activities and transactions in repos.

Comment: I am afraid I will need a bit more than that really. Something on the lines of: 1. Code Asset loaded with parameters x, y and z 2. HR accesses the asset for doing activity abc...